# C++: Access embedded resource from dll

Tags: c++, dll, embedded-resource

I have a c++ dll project, in which, I have embedded some raw data through "resource.rc" file.

```
IDR_TEMPLATE1           RCDATA                "areaTemplate.bin"
```

Now I want to access the data of "areaTemplate.bin" file from the dll. How can I read the contents of "areaTemplate.bin" in a byte array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042.aspx) or [FindResourceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648043.aspx), then use [LoadResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046.aspx) and [LockResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047.aspx).

Use [SizeofResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648048.aspx) to get the size of datas.

Code:

```
HMODULE g_hModDll;

[...]

HRSRC hRscr = FindResource( g_hModDll, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDR_TEMPLATE1 ),
                            MAKEINTRESOURCE( RT_RCDATA ) );
if ( hRscr ) {
    HGLOBAL hgRscr = LoadResource( g_hModDll, hRscr );
    if ( hgRscr ) {
        PVOID pRscr = LockResource( hgRscr );
        DWORD cbRscr = SizeofResource( g_hModDll, hRscr );
    }
}
```

Be sure to read the following remark about LoadResource:

> **Remarks** The return type of LoadResource is HGLOBAL for backward
>   compatibility, not because the function returns a handle to a global
>   memory block. Do not pass this handle to the GlobalLock or GlobalFree
>   function.

There is no "unlock resource" or "free resource" APIs.

> **Remarks** The pointer returned by LockResource is valid until the module
>   containing the resource is unloaded. It is not necessary to unlock
>   resources because the system automatically deletes them when the
>   process that created them terminates.

Comment: At first it didn't work. After searching a bit, I found that, I have to initialize `g_hModDll` using `GetModuleHandle(L"mydll.dll")`.
Is there a way to enumerate the `L"mydll.dll"`, not hardcoding it in the program?

Comment: If "mydll.dll" is a regular Win32 C/C++ DLL, you could save the HMODULE (HINSTANCE) value in DllMain. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583.aspx Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 3):

As Manuell says, you use [FindResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042.aspx), [LoadResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046.aspx) and probably [LockResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SizeofResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I happen to have some code which does pulls out a resource and writes it to a file, and may help with your understanding of the API in question.

```
void WriteResourceToFile(
   HANDLE hFile,
   const _tstring &resourceName,
   const _tstring &resourceType,
   HMODULE hModule)
{
   HRSRC hResource = ::FindResource(
      hModule,
      resourceName.c_str(),
      resourceType.c_str());

   if (!hResource)
   {
      const DWORD lastError = ::GetLastError();

      throw CWin32Exception(
         _T("WriteResourceToFile() - FindResource"),
         lastError);
   }

   HGLOBAL hGlobal = ::LoadResource(hModule, hResource);

   if (!hGlobal)
   {
      const DWORD lastError = ::GetLastError();

      throw CWin32Exception(
         _T("WriteResourceToFile() - LoadResource"),
         lastError);
   }

   void *pData = ::LockResource(hGlobal);

   if (!pData)
   {
      const DWORD lastError = ::GetLastError();

      throw CWin32Exception(
         _T("WriteResourceToFile() - LockResource"),
         lastError);
   }

   const DWORD bytes = ::SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);

   DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

   if (!::WriteFile(hFile, pData, bytes, &bytesWritten, 0))
   {
      const DWORD lastError = ::GetLastError();

      throw CWin32Exception(
         _T("WriteResourceToFile() - WriteFile"),
         lastError);
   }

   if (bytesWritten != bytes)
   {
      throw CWin32Exception(
         _T("WriteResourceToFile() - WriteFile"),
         _T("Wrote less bytes (") + ToString(bytesWritten) +
         _T("( than expected: ") + ToString(bytes));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Determine the module handle of your DLL by locating a function
// you know resides in that DLL
HMODULE hModule;
GetModuleHandleExA(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT,
        (LPCSTR)&myDLLfuncName, &hModule)

HRSRC hRscr = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_TEMPLATE1),
                           MAKEINTRESOURCE(RT_RCDATA));
```