# Environment Path in DLL executed programs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

Maybe Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952206/c-access-embedded-resource-from-dll).
I have a C++ DLL I created in Visual Studio. In the DLL is a Class X with all functions public static and exported (using _declspec). I want to read a text file(for eg. 'file.txt' ) in one of the functions of the class.

```
_declspec(dllexport) void XClass::readFile()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("file.txt");
    if(!file.is_open()) return;
    int x;
    file>>x;
    cout<<x<<endl;
}
```

The Problem is, I don't know how to add the txt file to the DLL. I have added it to resources in the VS project, but it doesn't seem to add, because when I ran another project including the DLL file, `is_open()` fails. I also tried adding the file.txt to the new project, but without success. How to use resources in the DLL file, or better add them to DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read some data embedded in your program rather than a file, then you need to use Windows API like in the question you referenced. `ifstream` does not deal with embedded resources - this is a standard C++ class that does not know anything about Windows resources.

If you want to read a regular text file, you don't need to embed anything - just place the file in the directory from which you start the program.